# Different results when running in $() or not in it

Tags: zsh

This is one of the weirdest things I've come across.

```bash
➜  ~ cat word.txt
mere doctrine
➜  ~ tr ' ' '\n' < ~/word.txt
mere
doctrine
➜  ~ echo $(tr ' ' '\n' < ~/word.txt)
mere doctrine
```

I don't understand what is the difference between executing inside $() environment and executing directly.

I am using zsh on manjaro linux.

Comment: I've added an answer with useful links. If it works, please, accept the answer.

Comment: $ provides write substitution command

Comment: "*I am using zsh on manjaro linux*". Why is this question tagged with `bash`?

Comment: Related: ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).

Answer (score 1):

When you write, for example, `echo $(ls)`, [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) occurs.

The best practice is to add double quotes to [prevent word splitting](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2046):

```bash
➜  ~ echo "$(tr ' ' '\n' < word.txt)"
mere
doctrine
```